# APK file not working on some devices

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I have built an APK file from Android studio from Build -> Build APKs.
APK is able to install on different devices but its giving error in Android 8.0 devices. Error is sometimes like **"invalid resource path specified"** and **"There was a problem parsing the package"**.
I have tried to find the problem online but no succes. below is my gradle file.
Please help

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.remitnow.pay.remitnow"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
        implementation 'com.github.mukeshsolanki:android-otpview-pinview:1.1.0'

    }
```

Comment: use signed APK for latest version

Comment: have you use camera or phone storage ?

Comment: no just internet.